# Start YouTube upload at specific time, and shutdown computer afterwards?

Tags: shutdown, youtube

Is there such an application to start a upload to YouTube at a specific time, and then shutdown the computer afterwards? I'd rather upload around 2am when no one on my network is trying to use the internet, though I'm not usually up that late, and I don't want to leave the computer running after the upload is complete. Is there an application to assist with this?